# Alterar Request Headers para protocolo WS

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails, websocket, request

Tenho um app *Ionic* que utiliza uma API *Ruby on Rails*.
Para fazer a autenticação, estou utilizando as gems *Devise* e *tiddle* onde passo via interceptor do *AngularJs* **X-USER-EMAIL** e **X-USER-TOKEN** no *Request Header*
Tem uma parte da aplicação que utilizo a gem **websocket-rails** para efetuar algumas ações em *real-time*. Mas para que isso funcione preciso do usuário logado e o interceptor do angular não passa esses cabeçalhos pelo fato de ser uma requisição **WS** e não **HTTP**. O que fazer para estar autenticado ao utilizar o websocket?